# How to get link to user's timeline from Facebook Messanger Platform API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

Did I miss sth or it is impossible to get link to user's timeline from Facebook Messenger API?
According to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/user-profile User Profile API doesn't return link in fields.
Is there any other option?

Comment: No it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use the User Profile endpoint and use all the information for determining which Facebook user it matches to. If you image match the profile picture and match all the other information, and compare timezone to their location, it is probably possible, but it's probably not easy.

Making a workaround like this might not be a bad idea because Facebook seems to want to keep all the stuff seperate right now, as their user ID's are different for seemingly everything. The User Profile endpoint exists for personalization purposes, but it doesn't identify a user.

The user matching through login might also be useful as a outside of messenger solution, but I'm not sure exactly how that would be done.